# text game character collision detection problems

Tags: c++, console

I'm making a game where you avoid walls made of 'X's as you move down the screen, and if you hit an X you lose a shield and keep plowing through the X's without losing any more shields until you pop out into a character space where there isn't an X.

However, when running the code below along with some other unneccesary code it woks perfectly if I have stops placed in Visual Studio, but when I start to hit an 'X' wall while the code is running and walls moving quite fast it doesn't work right and you end up doing the plowing, but you lose all shields in the proccess and the X's don't disappear as you "plow" through them.

Here's the code:

```
char coll;  // the buffer for the collided char

if (theScreen.check_collision(player, xMove, yMove, coll) != true) {
    // no collision
    // get rid of old player placing
    theScreen.Insert(' ', player.get_location()[0], player.get_location()[1]);
    // put in new charater placing
    player.move(xMove, yMove);
    theScreen.Insert(player);
    numb_coll = 0;
} else {
    // collision
    if (coll == 'X' && player.get_shield() > 0) {
        for (int I = 0; I < numb_coll && numb_coll < player.get_location()[1]; I++) {
            theScreen.Insert(' ', player.get_location()[0],
                     player.get_location()[1] - (I + 1));
        }
        if (numb_coll == 0)
            player.set_shield(player.get_shield() - 1);
        numb_coll++;
        theScreen.Insert(player);
    }
    if (coll == 'X' && player.get_shield() <= 0)
        dead = true;
};
```

Comment: -1: Have you tried debugging this?  What did you discover?

Comment: just as a curasity what is that `for statement` suppose to do in your code?

Comment: what are the usage of argumentsyou are passing to `theScreen.Insert`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest a drastic re-organization of the code. This routine appears to be concerned with both *drawing* the player on the screen *and* changing the player's shield rating. I believe if you separate the *display* of the player from the *modification* of the player, your code will be easier to read and maintain.

Consider this:

```
theScreen.check_collision(player, xMove, yMove, coll) {
    /* your current check_collision code, which I hope is correct */
    if (collision)
        player.destroy_a_shield();
    return collision;
}
```

In your `player` object:

```
player.destroy_a_shield() {
    self.shield--;
    if (self.shield == 0)
        player.dead = true;
}
```

And then this code could look more like:

```
if (theScreen.check_collision(player, xMove, yMove, coll) {
    if (player.dead) 
        theScreen.insert("Ooops. Game over. Better luck next life.");
    else {
        for (int I = 0; I < numb_coll && numb_coll < player.get_location()[1]; I++) {
            theScreen.Insert(' ', player.get_location()[0],
                    player.get_location()[1] - (I + 1));
            }
        numb_coll++;
        theScreen.Insert(player);
    }
} else {
    theScreen.Insert(' ', player.get_location()[0], player.get_location()[1]);
    player.move(xMove, yMove);
    theScreen.Insert(player);
}
```

The idea of these modifications (rendered in pseudo-code, because I'm lazy and because I don't know exactly what the rest of your code looks like) is to separate the screen *display* from the game *mechanics*. (You've probably heard the term Model-View-Controller before -- this pattern accurately describes what I'm suggesting. Move the *business rules* out of your *views*. :)

Comment: It's also worth noting that I copied that `for` loop verbatim without really understanding _what_ it does. Maybe it should be shoved into a function with a good, descriptive name.